# running pypy3.5 with AWS Lambda custom runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, pypy, aws-lambda-layers

As AWS Lambda doesn't provide run time from pypy3, I am trying to use customer runtime from below link..
https://github.com/iopipe/lambda-runtime-pypy3.5?msclkid=0cdabf06b4c611eca1f350bd8a8e522e

But I don't know how to make changes in the bootstrap to run pypy3.5 from it so that it can run my python file under pypy3.5 binary. it always give runtime error, as I don't know where is the binary of pypy3.5 is located.

error:
/var/task/bootstrap: line 2: ./opt/pypy/bin/pypy3.5: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Is there a `'.'` at the beginning of `'./opt/pypy/bin/pypy3.5'`? What happens if you remove that?

Comment: didn't help,Response
{
  "errorMessage": "2022-04-06T07:45:32.182Z 13f74e15-530e-49ed-94a9-f22e8fe60197 Task timed out after 3.02 seconds"
}
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9001 (#0)
> GET /2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/next HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:9001
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Lambda-Runtime-Aws-Request-Id: 13f74e15-530e-49ed-94a9-f22e8fe60197
< Lambda-Runtime-Deadline-Ms: 1649231132163
< Lambda-Runtime-Invoked-Function-Arn: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:676804772699:function:mypypy3